# python setup.py install Invalid suntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I am very new to python so please bare with me.

I have downloaded and installed python 3 on my Mac.
I open up an Idle Shell, it begins:

```
Python 3.9.6 (v3.9.6:db3ff76da1, Jun 28 2021, 11:49:53) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>>
```

I then type, to change directory to a repo I downloaded from github:

```
>>> os.chdir("/Users/XXX/Desktop/spotiminder-master")
```

Then I type:

```
>>> python setup.py install
```

as per the instructions, but I get:

```
>>> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What do I need to do here? Appreciate your help.

Comment: "python setup.py install " is supposed to be entered directly from your terminal, not from the Python REPL as you did here. Exit Python first.

Comment: Run it from terminal not from python shell

Comment: Thank-you @ThierryLathuille. To eli5, what do i need to do in practical terms? I need to change the directory, which i have figured out how to do, but once I have done that what do I need to do differently for the setup install?

Comment: use python3 setup.py install